# Ansible Facts: How to get free memory in Solaris server?

Tags: ansible

In RHEL machines, `ansible_facts` gives free memory using `ansible_memfree_mb`.
What is the equivalent fact parameter in Solaris machines?

I am not seeing any same or related fact in Solaris.

Please help.

Comment: You should look at `ansible -m setup $HOSTNAME`, it gives you a list of all available facts.

Comment: You would expect the fact to have the same name under Solaris. If it doesn't exist I suspect that it simply isn't available. If you can figure out how to compute it, you could provide a [custom fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d).

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the source of [sunos.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/hardware/sunos.py) it seems there is nothing like memfree_mb reported back. Maybe it is possible for you to extend the module? After reading about [Solaris Memory](https://web.archive.org/web/20090909195206/http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/solaris_memory.html), `prtstat` or `prtdiag` might be possible to [Add custom facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#adding-custom-facts).